# How to use ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler in a spring-hateos project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

When using `spring-data-rest` there is a post processing of `Resource` classes returned from Controllers (e.g. `RepositoryRestControllers`). The proper `ResourceProcessor` is called in the post processing.

The class responsible for this is `ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` which is part of `spring-hateoas`.

I now have a project that only uses `spring-hateoas` and I wonder how to configure `ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` in such a scenario. It looks like the auto configuration part of it still resides in `spring-data-rest`.

Any hints on how to enable `ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` in a `spring-hateoas` context?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this recently too, and documentation on how to achieve this is non-existent. If you create a bean of type `ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter`, you seem to lose the the auto-configured `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and all its features. As such, I wanted to avoid using this bean or losing the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`, since all I really wanted was the `ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`.

You can't just add a `ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` via `WebMvcConfigurer.addReturnValueHandlers`, because what we need to do is actually override the entire list, as is what happens in  `ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet`:

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {

    super.afterPropertiesSet();

    // Retrieve actual handlers to use as delegate
    HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite oldHandlers = getReturnValueHandlersComposite();

    // Set up ResourceProcessingHandlerMethodResolver to delegate to originally configured ones
    List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> newHandlers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>();
    newHandlers.add(new ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler(oldHandlers, invoker));

    // Configure the new handler to be used
    this.setReturnValueHandlers(newHandlers);
}
```

So, without a better solution available, I added a `BeanPostProcessor` to handle setting the List of handlers on an existing `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConditionalOnBean(ResourceProcessor.class)
public class ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private final Collection<ResourceProcessor<?>> resourceProcessors;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) {

            RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean;

            List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlers =
                    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getReturnValueHandlers();

            HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite delegate =
                    handlers instanceof HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite ?
                            (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite) handlers :
                            new HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite().addHandlers(handlers);

            requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setReturnValueHandlers(Arrays.asList(
                    new ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler(delegate,
                            new ResourceProcessorInvoker(resourceProcessors))));

            return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
        }

        else return bean;
    }
}
```

This has seemed to work so far...